# Migrate from POSIX I/O (open, etc.) to C standard I/O (fopen, etc.)

Tags: c, linux, io, posix, c-standard-library

I'm trying to migrate project written using unbuffered I/O ( `open()`, `read()`, `write()` functions) to buffered I/O ( `fopen()`, `fread()`, `fwrite()` functions).

I came across some dummy problem: Adapting zoo of `open()` flags to `fopen()` set `r,r+,w,w+,a,a+`.

It seems to be boring and error-prone. Is there some other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I would use `grep | sort | uniq` to find all the cases in the source
code, then work out their translations, and write a simple Python script
to replace.

Answer (score 0):

You can write some C macros with parameters (called `open()`, `close()` etc.) that expand to the right call. However, it is error prone as well. Therefore, I'd rather rely on some powerful editor (e.g., vim) and regular expressions for changing all occurences.